# Where can I find a example for IPC using Apache Arrow?

Tags: pyarrow, apache-arrow

I am new to Apache Arrow and want to run some tests re IPC setup (java or python). 
Any other Arrow resources I should be looking at?

Answer (score 1):

- There is a [pull request](https://github.com/apache/arrow/pull/5723/files) under review demonstrating the basics of java.
- Similar python documentation is available on the [Apache Arrow Website](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/ipc.html)

Comment: Would I ever use Arrow for low latency IPC?

Comment: Can you define low latency?